# Select context dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

in my models i have contexts like

```
acts_as_taggable_on :sport, :music
```

in the console i can do this

```
@student = Student.first
@student.sport_list = ("baseball, soccer")
@student.save

@student.music_list = ("rock, pop")
@student.save

@student.sport_list  
[baseball, soccer]

@student.music_list
[rock, pop]
```

All this works right but, in views I want to do this dynamic
I catch in one string the context selected between others contexts by JavaScript for example:

```
mycontext = music
```

my doubt is:  Its possible make dynamic do

```
@student.mycontext_list = "rock, pop"
```

because I get the following error undefined method `mycontext_list=' for Student:0xb4475d4c

greetings friends!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
 @student.send :"#{mycontext}_list=", "rock, pop"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to define a method that accepts a string/symbol as an input

```
class Student
  def mycontext_list(string)
    self.send("#{string}_list".to_sym)
  end
end
```

Whatever string Javascript passes will then be used to call an appropriately named method (with _list appended to the end of it).

Comment: senk you very much to!!! Tnxs to Ron and mshakhan for help me ... I hope in future help to somebody lol !!!

Comment: If you accept the answer to your problem, that would help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

its already given there [mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

```
@student.set_tag_list_on(mycontext, "rock, pop")
```